# Error when running my test plan in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, test-planning

Hello I don't know what happened but when I'm running my test plan in jmeter the results doesn't show. the last thing that I did is adding a jmeter graph plugins

error:

````
```2020-10-22 17:01:12,305 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2020-10-22 17:01:12,305 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2020-10-22 17:01:12,305 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2020-10-22 17:01:12,306 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2020-10-22 17:01:12,306 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
2020-10-22 17:01:12,306 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
2020-10-22 17:01:23,000 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
2020-10-22 17:01:23,000 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1
2020-10-22 17:01:23,000 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
2020-10-22 17:01:23,001 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
2020-10-22 17:01:23,112 INFO o.a.j.v.ViewResultsFullVisualizer: Add JavaFX to your Java installation if you want to use renderer: org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.RenderInBrowser
2020-10-22 17:01:48,757 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='/Users/johnnatividad/Desktop/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin'
2020-10-22 17:01:48,758 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='/Users/johnnatividad/Desktop/graph'
2020-10-22 17:01:48,853 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
2020-10-22 17:01:48,860 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 5.0
2020-10-22 17:01:48,861 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
2020-10-22 17:01:51,306 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2020-10-22 17:01:51,307 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2020-10-22 17:01:51,307 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2020-10-22 17:01:51,308 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.'
2020-10-22 17:01:51,308 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.'
2020-10-22 17:01:51,463 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2020-10-22 17:01:51,495 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2020-10-22 17:01:51,495 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2020-10-22 17:01:51,495 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2020-10-22 17:01:51,495 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2020-10-22 17:01:51,497 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2020-10-22 17:01:51,497 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2020-10-22 17:01:51,498 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2020-10-22 17:01:51,505 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2020-10-22 17:01:51,506 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Thread Group 1-1,6,main]
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerFactory.getImplementation(HTTPSamplerFactory.java:96) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:61) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1281) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1270) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:630) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "your_proxy_port"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHCAbstractImpl.<clinit>(HTTPHCAbstractImpl.java:51) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.3]
    ... 9 more
2020-10-22 17:01:51,506 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2020-10-22 17:01:51,506 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
````

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "your_proxy_port"

JMeter expects the [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) port to be a number, if you copied and pasted the [JMeter command-line arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) or [system.properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) and they contain `your_proxy_port` - either remove the relevant line(s) or update it to match your proxy server port if you're using the proxy for accessing the Internet.

The relevant command line argument is `-P` and the properties are `http.proxyPort` and `https.proxyPort`

More information: [Using JMeter behind a proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)

Comment: yay its working now... thank you so much

Comment: got it now thank you